# Fourier Step method for combined time derivative

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-transform

The following equation
$$\partial_t U = i\partial_x^2U$$
can be solved using a step-wise Fourier transformation method:
$$U(x, t+\Delta t) = F^{-1}\left(\exp(i\cdot \Delta t\cdot k^2)F(U(x, t))\right)$$
But is it possible to apply the same method to an extended equation, which looks like
$$\partial_t^2U+\partial_tU=i\partial_x^2 U$$
and if yes, how?